# Relations on a set.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

State the smallest relation containing the relation
$$\{(1,2),(2,1),(2,3),(3,4),(4,1)\}$$
that is:

a) reflexive and transitive.

b) reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

For me reflexive would be something like: $\{(1,2),(1,2)\}$;
transitive would be like $\{(1,1)\}$ or $\{(3,1)\}$ but these two are not in the relation. Therefore, I don't know how to get the one that is both reflexive and transitive. As well as one that has all three properties. I have to admit that I am kind of lost here.

Comment: Could you tell us what you've tried? It's difficult for us to help you if you don't show us what your ideas on the problem are.

Comment: Please share your thoughts on the problem, and describe what's giving you trouble. For example: Do you know what it means for a relation to be reflexive? Or symmetric? Or transitive? Please keep in mind that phrasing a question as an order is considered by many to be rude, and will cause your question to be ignored.

Comment: for me transitive would be (1,1) but it is not part of the relation. So I am not sure.

Comment: I do hope that some one would be kind enough to help me out.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with $\{(1,2),(1,2)\}$ ? This is just the set $\{(1,2)\}$, it is not a reflexive relation, and it's not a relation containing the given one.

Comment: I do not understand this is why I am asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we let $X = \{(1,2),(2,1),(2,3),(3,4),(4,1)\}$, then the smallest relation on $X$ that is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive is $\{(1,2),(2,1)\}$. Note that for a relation to be smaller and symmetry to be satisfied, you would have to have a relation of form $\{(x,x)\}$. The same goes for the smallest relation that is reflexive and transitive.

Comment: Ok, would that mean to be reflexive and transitive the relation would have to be like {(2,2)}, and since this relation X has none of this form than it does not exist?

Comment: No. We don't have a relation of the form $\{(x,x)\}$, so the next best thing we can look for is a relation of the form $\{(x,y),(y,x)\}$. And we have such a relation - look at the definitions of reflexivity and transitivity. Obviously they are satisfied by $\{(1,2),(2,1)\}$.

Comment: ok, Then if I understood correctly, the only smallest relation that satisfies both (a) and (b) would be {(1,2),(2,1)}.